# How to search for multiple strings in a text file

Tags: java, string, algorithm

i am working in text files. I want to implement a search algorithm in Java. I have a text files i need to search.

If I want to find one word I can do it by just putting all the text into the hashmap and store each word's occurrence. But is there any algorithm if i want to search for two strings (or may be more)?  Should i hash the strings in pair of two ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on the size of the text file. There are usually several cases you should consider:

1. Lot's of queries on very short documents (web pages, texts of essay length etc). Text distribution like normal language. A simple O(n^2) algorithm is fine. For a query of length n just take a window of length n and slide it over. Compare and move the window until you find a match. This algorithm does not care about words, so you just see the whole search as a big string (including spaces). This is probably what most browsers does. KMP or Boyer Moore is not worth the effort, since the O(n^2) case is very rare.
2. Lot's of queries on one large document. Preprocess your document and store it preprocessed. Common storage options are suffix trees and inverted lists. If you have multiple documents you can build one document from when by concatenating them and storing the end of documents seperately. This is the way to go for document databases where the collection is almost constant.
3. If you have several documents where you have a high redundancy and your collections changes often, use KMP or Boyer Moore. For example if you want to find certain sequences in DNA data and you often get new sequences to find as well new DNA from experiments, the O(n^2) part of the naive algorithm would kill your time.

There are probably lot's of more possibilities that need different algorithms and data structures, so you should figure out which one is the best in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Some more detail is required before suggesting an approach:

Are you searching for whole words only or any substring?

Are you going to search for many different words in the same unchanged file?

Do you know the words you want to search for all at once?

There are many efficient (linear) search algorithms for strings. If possible I'd suggest using one that's already been written for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

One simple idea is to use a sliding window hash with the window the same size as the search string.  Then in a single pass you can quickly check to see where the window hash matches the hash of your search string. Where it matches you double check to see if you've got a real match.

Comment: I want to search a word that may be not the substring (i dont want to deal with wild characters as of now). Yes, I am going to search for many different words in the same file. No, I dont know the words which I want to search searching depends on the user. Yes , I got the idea of the sliding window but the problem is size of the sliding window as i can search a word or two words which are together. ex. if I can search in this web page as 1. many 2. many different 3. many different words. Here, what can be the size of sliding window ?

Comment: Rabin Karp is only practicably comparable to KMP or Boyer Moore in some special circumstances (searching more than one string at the same time basically), otherwise it's best to go with one of the others. IF you want to search for larger sets of words at once, Rabin Karp gets interesting and is trivial to implement.

Comment: How does a browser does it ? like chrome ? which algo does it uses. Because I am trying to get effect which the browser has

Comment: If you want to search for 3 different words of different lengths at the same time you can maintain 3 different hash windows in the same pass.

How fast do you need this to go and how often is the document searched? Ask yourself if it's worth going to the trouble to pre-process the document. If it's user driven searches like a browser I would have thought the above methods would be fine.

Comment: Its a Text file so I want to preprocess the file as it wont change. The text file is just for viewing the its not editable. So any I apply any other thing I found this ... I think this is interesting http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/

Comment: If the file does not change ever, and you are expecting a lot of searches, you should store this file as a suffix tree. Searching a substring on a suffix tree is only O(m) where m is the length of the string (whereas a search algorithm needs at least O(n), n being the length of the text). However building the tree needs O(n^2), so you need enough queries to make up for this.